Gap between the given correlation parameter and the empirical correlation in (Gaussian) copula simulation
Now I am trying to simulate normal copula with initial parameters being a correlation matrix of my wish. I found that the empirical correlations are generally lower than what is entered as the initial parameters.
To simplify the problematic, let's consider a bivariate Gaussian copula with initial parameter being 0.5.
I created the following code in R as an illustration:
converg_corr_copula <- function(num_sim, n, param){
  
  result <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=2))[-1,]
  names(result) <- c("seed","corr_emp")

  for (i in 1:n){
    
    set.seed(i)
    cp_gaus <- normalCopula(param = param, dim = 2,dispstr = "un")
    copula_sim <- rCopula(n = num_sim, copula = cp_gaus) %>% as.data.frame()
    result[nrow(result)+1,] <- c(i,cor(copula_sim)[2])
    
  }
  
  return(c(mean(result$corr_emp),sd(result$corr_emp)))
}

lapply(c(1e2,1e3,1e4,1e5,1e6,1e7), converg_corr_copula, n = 50, param = 0.5)


From the result, we can see that the empirical is centered around 0.48, with standard deviation diminishing as number of simulations increases.
[[1]]
[1] 0.48122020 0.06987925

[[2]]
[1] 0.47687772 0.02583187

[[3]]
[1] 0.481539045 0.007837956

[[4]]
[1] 0.48220804 0.00260011

[[5]]
[1] 0.4827420303 0.0008324203

[[6]]
[1] 0.4826076828 0.0002399406

Does anyone of you have an idea on why it is the case please?

@Glen_b thanks for your explanation. After checking some related posts, it is clear now.

I've posted a slightly expanded version of the comment. I may return to add a little more detail; this seems to be a fairly common issue.

The value of linear correlations are not preserved across nonlinear transformation of the margins. The parameter, $\rho$ measures the Pearson correlation for a Gaussian copula when the margins are Gaussian. When they're not, the correlation is not $\rho$ in general.
For uniform margins the Pearson correlation is typically a little lower. With some margins it might be higher, for others  perhaps lower still.
Indeed, for most combinations of marginal distributions the relationship is no longer linear.
This is why when working with copulas, focus tends to be on monotonic correlations, which are preserved across strictly montonic-increasing transformations.
